# XML Lite parsing issue - ignore invalid data when parsing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xml-parsing, xmllite

I use XML Lite from microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Is there a way to ignore any validation errors it might do(I get some obscure error on a node related to "" - although the XML input seems just fine) and just continue with next nodes ?

I have the reading loop like this

```
while ( !reader->IsEOF())
{
        result = reader->Read(&nodeType);
        if (result != S_OK)
        {
            //just ignore cuurrent read and continue reading more from XML
            continue; // does not work
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returned by XmlLite? Invalid characters? XmlLite is a W3C compliant XML parser, meaning that it is by design to choke on invalid XML files with invalid characters, and there is not such a feature to ignore invalid character and move on. The options are:

1. Use XmlLite or other compliant XML parser to generate the XML. In this way you won't get invalid character at the first place.
2. Filter out invalid characters if you have control of the source data. XmlLite supports XML 1.0, with a range of valid character as #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF].

Other than that, XmlLite probably may not be your choice.

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was not parsing the whole XML document (and that was not obvious :-)) as I was expected and the problem was because of that.

Comment: Interestingly, XmlLite Reader starts to support non-blocking feature since Win8, meaning that you can return E_PENDING in your IStream/ISequentialStream implementation when not all data is available, which I believe is your case. The Read() method will return E_PENDING accordingly, but the next Read() call will resume the parsing if more data is available in the stream. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753140(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.